# How do I create an Observable array which is the result of averaging mapped arrays

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to figure out the hourly average of this collection called `meterdata` where each document in the collection has an array called `hourlyarray` which has a length of 24.

This code snippet maps the `[0]` all of the `hourlyarray`s and averages them together in a single number.

It wrote works perfectly, but only averages the first position. Is there a simple way to programmatically create an Observable on my component.ts to run this 24 times and then to batch all the results together in a single array?

```
this.avg0 = collectionRef.collection('meterdata', 
ref=> ref.where("day", "==", day )).valueChanges()
.pipe((map(data => data.map(d => d.hourlyarray[0])
.reduce((acc, avg) => acc + avg, 0)/data.length)));
```

Related: Is it not intelligent to be doing this calculation on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

`.pipe(switchMap(data => from(data)), map(arrayofdata => arrayofdata.reduce(...)))` should work if I understood your intention correctly. In short, it would covert your `hourlyarray` to an `Observable` and apply reduction among all the elements in that array.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - unless i'm not implementing it correctly. `this.avg = collectionRef.collection('meterdata', ref=> ref.where("day", "==", day )).valueChanges().pipe(switchMap(data => from(data.hourlyarray), reduce(...)));` results in an error `Expression expected.`, and if I plug in my reduce() part in, i get `Property 'hourlyarray' does not exist on type 'DocumentData[]'`. Do I append this code to what I have already? Thank you.

Comment: @EzraButler, I fixed typo; retry again.

Comment: `this.avg = collectionRef.collection('meterdata', ref=> ref.where("day", "==", day )).valueChanges().pipe(switchMap(data => from(data.hourlyarray)), reduce(...));` this still results in `ERROR in src/app/archive/archive.component.ts(137,135): error TS2339: Property 'hourlyarray' does not exist on type 'DocumentData[]'.
    src/app/archive/archive.component.ts(137,150): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'reduce'.`

Comment: @EzraButler, it says that `data` is actually the array itself. So just get rid of the `hourlyarray`. You have to pass your array into `from` to convert it to `Observable`.

Comment: I know the data is an array. I have 20 arrays each with the same length of 24 which  I want to create an array with the length of 24 that is the average of the original 20 arrays.

Comment: @EzraButler, see edits. If they does not work, make sure you update your post with whole code and types included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205704/discussion-between-ezra-butler-and-sereja-bogolubov).